# Android-WebView's onReceivedHttpAuthRequest() not called again

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, basic-authentication, webviewclient

I am using a webview based application where i am rendering a url in the webview. The Url has a HTTP auth .

When i launch the url very first time,its onReceivedHttpAuthRequest() is called and I display a dialog for user to enter the authentication credentials that is auth username and password.

```
@Override
public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) {
        final WebView mView = view;
        final HttpAuthHandler mHandler = handler;

        final EditText usernameInput = new EditText(mActivity);
        usernameInput.setHint("Username");

        final EditText passwordInput = new EditText(mActivity);
        passwordInput.setHint("Password");
        passwordInput.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);

        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(mActivity);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        ll.addView(usernameInput);
        ll.addView(passwordInput);

        Builder authDialog = new AlertDialog
                .Builder(mActivity)
                .setTitle("Authentication")
                .setView(ll)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        mHandler.proceed(usernameInput.getText().toString(), passwordInput.getText().toString());
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        mView.stopLoading();
                        onLoadListener.onAuthCancel((MyWebView)mView, mTitleTextView);
                    }
                });

        if(view!=null)
            authDialog.show();

    }
```

On Submitting the request proceed well and the url is loaded. But After I exit the app using back button(not sending in background), if i launch it again and tru to load the same url it directly load the url without asking for credentials that is onReceivedHttpAuthRequest() is never called again.

I am also clearing the credentials on app exit using following code:

```
WebViewDatabase webDB = WebViewDatabase.getInstance(BrowserActivity.this);
    if(webDB!=null){
        if(webDB.hasFormData())
            webDB.clearFormData();
        if(webDB.hasUsernamePassword())
            webDB.clearUsernamePassword();
        if(webDB.hasHttpAuthUsernamePassword())
            webDB.clearHttpAuthUsernamePassword();
    }
webView.clearCache(true);
```

Also i am clearing all the webview cache, cookies, and application's cache directory and the webview databases:

```
BrowserActivity.this.deleteDatabase("webview.db");
BrowserActivity.this.deleteDatabase("webviewCache.db");
```

I don't know why this is happening. Is there anybody who can help me on this.
At least on the issue that why onReceivedHttpAuthRequest() is not called?

Comment: Are you certain that the code you have to clear the saved username/password is being executed?

Comment: yes it is executed. Also when i force stop the app and then launch, it asks for auth.

Comment: OK, so it sounds like only the case that doesn't work is when you use the back button? When exactly do you run the code that clears the database?

Comment: 1. Clearing Webview cache.
2. Delete database.
3. Clear cookies.
4. Deleting cache directory

Comment: Yes, but what action triggers these events? What callback do you listen for? Can you try moving the code into your Activity.onPause() ?

Comment: I am clearing all data in when i destroy the activity.

Comment: Hi mohitum007, did you find a proper solution. I am also stuck with this issue?

Comment: @Thushara, Not yet, I ahve changed the functionality now. But still searching for the same.

Answer (score 4):

1. before load the url,set Authorization information in http headers

   Map extraHeaders = new HashMap<>(); 
   extraHeaders.put("Authorization", "TlRM");//the value is Casually set.
   webView.loadUrl(url, extraHeaders);
2. in WebViewClient

   @Override 
   public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler,
                          String host, String realm) { 
       view.loadUrl(url);//reload the url.
       handler.proceed(account, password); 
   }
3. I resolve this issue,but I can not speak English very well. 
   Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is webview store previous connection cookies. So we need to manually clear them and store new cookie data for the current url. we can do it like this.

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        URL urls = new URL(url);
        String authStr = "";
        if (!params.isEmpty()) {
            authStr = params.get(0).getValue() + ":"
                    + params.get(1).getValue();
        }

        String authEncoded = Base64.encodeBytes(authStr.getBytes());

        connection = (HttpURLConnection) urls
                .openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(5100);
        connection.setReadTimeout(5200);
        connection.setDoOutput(false);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "
                + authEncoded);
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        String cookie = cookieManager.getCookie(connection.getURL().toString());
        if (cookie != null) {
            connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
        }
        connection.connect();

        responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        InputStream content = connection.getInputStream();
        response = convertStreamToString(content);
        content.close();

        // Get cookies from responses and save into the cookie manager. session is created only in rest call url
        List<String> cookieList = connection.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie");
        if (cookieList != null) {
            for (String cookieTemp : cookieList) {
                cookieManager.setCookie(connection.getURL().toString(), cookieTemp);
            }
        }

    }catch (SocketTimeoutException es){
        response = ConnectionStatus.TIME_OUT.name();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        response = e.getMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        connection.disconnect();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using "Authorization" header instead of using onReceivedHttpAuthRequest()

Comment: how even afetr adding i am unable to receive onhttprequestmethod only